# AWS-Cloud9 Time Accumulates Too Rapidly

Tags: aws-cloud9

Recently migrated my Cloud9 account to Amazon's AWS-Cloud9 platform. Have created a Micro t2 environment to run simple code using Cisco's Scheme 9.5, Lua 5.3, and Python 3. The platform runs beautifully and is very fast. But the clock that keeps track of my 750/mo free-tier hours runs about 100 times faster than my actual online time. So, for example, the clock indicates more than 200 hours used for no more than two hours of online time. Not doing anything fancy, just using the terminal to run simple stand-alone code. Have asked AWS support why this is happening and what can be done to make their time-keeping agree with actual usage. They haven't answered that specific question, instead referring me to articles about properly setting up an environment. I believe the Micro t2 environment is setup according to AWS suggestions.

Q. Why does that clock run so fast?

Q. Have others had similar complaints?

Q. What can be done about it, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible remedies you can see why your EC2 instance is racking up so many hours.

- You can manually verify this by looking at the CloudWatch metrics and checking the `CPUUtilization` metric for your instance. This should show you when your instance has been active. The EC2 instance should have Basic Monitoring which includes this metrics at a 5 minute interval for the past two weeks.
- You can configure AWS Cloud9 to automatically shut down the EC2 instance when not in use via the settings under `Preferences -> Project Settings -> EC2 Instance`. **NOTE**: It will only shut down if there are no tabs open with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a technical support group I discovered that there were instances of my account being used that I was not aware of. Using one of the tools provided by AWS I was able to terminate/delete all those unwanted instances, just leaving the simple free-tier operation I wanted. This will help a lot to control connect time.